How can I write the text in another language instead of English?
Based on the answer in tried in Vietnamese
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
list = {{{6, 8, 5}, {7, 4, 2}, {9, 3, 1}}, {{6, 8, 5}, {7, 4, 3}, {9, 
     1, 2}}, {{6, 8, 5}, {7, 4, 3}, {9, 2, 1}}, {{6, 9, 1}, {7, 2, 
     3}, {8, 4, 5}}, {{6, 9, 1}, {7, 2, 3}, {8, 5, 4}}, {{6, 9, 
     1}, {7, 2, 4}, {8, 3, 5}}};

data = Table[{pA, pB, pC} = points;
  mylist = {pA, pB, pC, 
    Subtract @@ Expand[CoplanarPoints[{pA, pB, pC, {x, y, z}}]] == 
     0}, {points, list}]

toX[e_] := 
 StringReplace[ToString[TeXForm[e]], {"\\}" -> ")", "\\{" -> "("}]

fileName = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "Vietnamese.tex"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName], DeleteFile[fileName]];
file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity];
WriteString[file, 
  "\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n" <> 
   "\\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}\n\
" <> "\\usepackage{amsmath}\n" <> "\\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}\n" <> 
   "\\usepackage{amsthm}\n" <> "\\theoremstyle{definition}\n" <> 
   "\\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}\n" <> "\\begin{document}\n"];
Do[WriteString[file, 
   "\\begin{ex}\n" <> "Phương trình mặt phẳng qua ba điểm $A" <> 
    toX[data[[n, 1]]] <> "$, $B" <> toX[data[[n, 2]]] <> "$, $C" <> 
    toX[data[[n, 3]]] <> "$ là $" <> toX[data[[n, 4]]] <> 
    "$\n\\end{ex}\n"], {n, 1, Length@data}];
WriteString[file, "\\end{document}\n"];
Close[file]

The LaTeX generated by Mathematica is
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\begin{document}
\begin{ex}
Ph\:01b0\:01a1ng tri`nh m\:1eb7t ph\:1eb3ng qua ba \:0111i\:1ec3m $A(6,8,5)$, $B(7,4,2)$, $C(9,3,1)$ la` $x-5 y+7 z-1=0$
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
Ph\:01b0\:01a1ng tri`nh m\:1eb7t ph\:1eb3ng qua ba \:0111i\:1ec3m $A(6,8,5)$, $B(7,4,3)$, $C(9,1,2)$ la` $2 x+3 y-5 z-11=0$
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
Ph\:01b0\:01a1ng tri`nh m\:1eb7t ph\:1eb3ng qua ba \:0111i\:1ec3m $A(6,8,5)$, $B(7,4,3)$, $C(9,2,1)$ la` $2 x-y+3 z-19=0$
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
Ph\:01b0\:01a1ng tri`nh m\:1eb7t ph\:1eb3ng qua ba \:0111i\:1ec3m $A(6,9,1)$, $B(7,2,3)$, $C(8,4,5)$ la` $2 x-z-11=0$
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
Ph\:01b0\:01a1ng tri`nh m\:1eb7t ph\:1eb3ng qua ba \:0111i\:1ec3m $A(6,9,1)$, $B(7,2,3)$, $C(8,5,4)$ la` $13 x-y-10 z-59=0$
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
Ph\:01b0\:01a1ng tri`nh m\:1eb7t ph\:1eb3ng qua ba \:0111i\:1ec3m $A(6,9,1)$, $B(7,2,4)$, $C(8,3,5)$ la` $5 x-y-4 z-17=0$
\end{ex}
\end{document}

and PDF file.

It means, the code does not support Vietnamese. How can I write the text in another language instead of English?

Isn’t the .tex file correct? What software is converting the .tex file to the incorrect.pdf file? Why do you think this is a Mathematica problem?

And just remember to add \usepackage[vietnamese,english]{babel} to preamble also, else Latex will not compile it.

I do not think you need \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam} if you use \usepackage[vietnamese,english]{babel} but this is a Latex thing now and not Mathematica. For me it worked without using \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}. Using lualatex compiler with TexLive 2023 on Linux.

@Nasser Only need \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

Specifying CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8" in OpenWrite[] seems to produce the right output. (I don't know Vietnamese, so I'm not sure.)
file = OpenWrite[fileName, PageWidth -> Infinity, 
  CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]


Yes, verified this made it work. V 14

@Michael E2 It works fine. Thank you very much
